# Timer in FreeBSD kernel module?

Tags: timer, kernel, freebsd, kernel-module, callout

I'd like to let my kernel module periodically do something (a certain time interval, like 10 sec) in FreeBSD kernel. Any example for doing that?

I searched and found that there are functions like callout/timeout(old), but they seem complicated, and I cannot find good examples for them. For `callout'', it seems that`callout_reset'' is similar to the function I want (arguments include a handler and a time interval). But it seems to only execute once. So I'm confused.

Examples are the best, even for function ``timeout''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use callout(9).  As for examples...  Hm, for a real-world code you could take a look at this: http://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/sys/dev/iscsi/iscsi.c?revision=275925&view=markup; search for is_callout.  Basically, you need 'struct timeout', a function that will get called periodically, and then you need to get the timer ticking:

```
struct callout callout;

static void
callout_handler(void *whatever)
{
        // do your stuff, and make sure to get called again after 'seconds'.
        callout_schedule(&callout, seconds * hz);
}

static void
start_ticking(void)
{
        callout_init(&callout, 1);
        callout_reset(&callout, seconds * hz, callout_handler, whatever);
}
```

Comment: What does `seconds * hz` mean here? I saw several examples with this but it seems no definition for `hz` in source code. When I use values like `10000`, I believe this is likely less than a second since it's _ticks_. But my handler seems triggered after a long time.

Comment: I mean, how to convert this _ticks_ to _seconds_ .

Comment: "seconds" is seconds, seconds * hz is ticks.  Don't define hz, use the extern definition from <sys/kernel.h>.